# IIS Worker Process not releasing memory until any other Application required memory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-10

I have six websites on IIS and its worker process memory is around 1.5 GB and its not decreasing after process completion until I run some other applications on system which required memory, then IIS Worker Process memory is decreasing with increasing of other applications memory.

Comment: this sounds fairly normal, to be honest; I know that in recent versions of .NET Core they added some controls to allow you to make it more aggressive in limiting the working set, but by default: if nobody else actively wants the memory...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the below step. its works for me.

Step 1:
To enable GC memory tuning, add the following setting to the Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config

```
<configuration>
  <!-- ... -->
  <runtime>
    <performanceScenario value="HighDensityWebHosting"  />
    <!-- ... -->
```

link >
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/whitepapers/whats-new-in-aspnet-45-and-visual-studio-2012

Comment: The IIS worker process set up locally increased from 4MB to 60MB after a few page refreshes of a ASP.Net Web Pages razor website. After exhausting all options relating to the code, a blank .cshtml page was set up and the memory appeared to continue to increase after several refreshes after recycle to 30MB. Updating the config file kept the memory at 16MB. Would be good to know what is taking up the memory and not releasing it for a blank page. The other ASP.NET Core project set up locally seemed to hover around 5MB.